# How to sync software setting between two or more computers?

Tags: windows-10, sync

I have 3 computers I usually use, when I make changes to some setting in application on one computer, I have to redo those changes again in the other two. Is there any way to sync software setting between different computers?

Windows 10 offer some Windows setting syncing, which is acceptable to a certain extent. The real problem is with application syncing. MS Office, Chrome, Firefox, etc can sync setting for you. But what about other apps without native sync support? What option do we have?

Thanks

Comment: use roaming profile: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Roaming_user_profile

Comment: @magicandre1981 This is really not ideal and probably an overkill just for syncing settings for some apps. It takes time, a long time if over the Internet; and will not always get the job done.

Comment: @magicandre1981 correct me if I'm wrong, but I think roaming profile does require you to join to AD. In this case, all 3 computers are not joined to AD (home use).

Comment: ok, in this case you can't use it